# Do modules prevent the need to use the DOMContentLoaded listener?

Tags: javascript, script-tag, deferred-loading

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 

});
```

I read that this event listener made sure, for regular scripts, that the JS wasn't going to reference nodes that hadn't been loaded yet. The content executes *after* DOMContentLoaded has been fired).

I've also [read](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer) that a module is executed *before* `DOMContentLoaded` is fired (due to the `defer` attribute it has built in).

The modules I've used seem to not need the `DOMContentLoaded` listener. Can I confirm the `DOMContentLoaded` listener isn't needed by them to access nodes correctly?

Also, I can't think of how to test this so I'm asking here. If you know how I could, please do share!

Comment: Wouldn't the test be to run your code with and without the event listener to see if it behaves the same?

Comment: @arieljuod yeah it does seem to work but the fact that that article said modules are executed before DOMContentLoaded fires spooked me. Can you confirm a module will never need this listener to access nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this article should clear things for you, it has great pictures https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/#the-position-matters

When `defer` is present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing, therefore you can guarantee that the script gets access to the nodes without `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: This articule is great for understanding the defer and async attributes on a legacy script but doesn't cover the more modern type="module" scripts.

Answer (score 4):

When using `defer`, the scripts will indeed execute after the page has been fully downloaded in the order that they appeared.

You can see [here](https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html#script) a schema representing the behavior.

[image]

- [`<script>`](https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html#script)

[image]

- [`<script defer>`](https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html#script-defer)

[image]

In any case, scripts are always executed before `DOMContentLoaded`, you can test that theory here :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    alert("Alert from script")
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Alert from jQuery")
  });
</script>

<!-- Alerts "Alert from defer -->
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript" src="https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5tF5s4mB"></script>
```

And unless you remove the alert from the ready state, all scripts will execute before them, otherwise they get executed in the order they appear in the `DOM`.

So you can be sure that all code inside `DOMContentLoaded` will be able to access the fully loaded `DOM`.

On an end note, do watch out of [`defer`'s compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer) across all browsers.

Script attributes `async` and `defer`, [don’t block `DOMContentLoaded`](https://tr.javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded#domcontentloaded-and-scripts). JavaScript modules behave like `defer`, they don’t block it too.

This can be tested using `type="module"`

```html
<script type="module">
  alert("Alert from script")
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Page loaded")
</script>
```

As you can see, the page loads before executing any modules, no matter the order.

Comment: Thanks @IslamElshobokshy. Good link you shared. But my question was specifically: can I confirm modules don't need the `DOMContentLoaded` event (like I was shown scripts need to) to access all the nodes fine?

Comment: As he (well) explained, you can see you don't need to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event.