# use `document` in external TypeScript file within Astro project

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, astrojs

I've switched to Astro after some difficulties getting Vite+Eleventy to cooperate. I have everything like I want it *except* that I can't have an external TypeScript module that interacts with the `document`. I think it may be two problems tied in a knot, or maybe a misunderstanding of the [sparse documentation on external TS/JS files](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-components/#loading-external-scripts).

**Problem 1: `public/` and import paths**

JavaScript files can easily live under `public/`, but **TypeScript is not transpiled**. I tried adding `public` to my tsconfig, but it didn't help.

Importing in the frontmatter of a page is done in "Astro scope", which lets me use paths relative to the page file. TS imported this way transpiles and works *except* when looking for `document`.

Importing a module from within a `<script>` tag on the page is "client scope". *If* my TS code elsewhere under `src` is getting transpiled, I still don't have a *determinate, served location* to use for the import path (in other words, I could probably figure it out, but it would be fragile).

**Problem 2: `document` undefined**

I must use `<script is:inline>` or `<script type="module">` in order to have a script remain embedded in the HTML for "client scope". These scripts have access to `window` and `document`. However, they don't have access to any modules imported and transpiled in "Astro scope", nor to the [Runtime API](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/).

Import paths within an inline script tag always start looking at the root URL (i.e., `public/`), so I'm back to Problem 1.

(Incidentally, after a little research, it seems `DOMContentLoaded` isn't necessary with normal modules, but I think Astro is doing something to change that.)

**my setup**

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "extends": "astro/tsconfigs/strictest",
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "public/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "astro/client"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "^layouts/*": [ "src/layouts/*" ],
      "^scripts/*": [ "src/scripts/*" ]
    }
  }
}
```

`src/scripts/sample.ts`

```
type NotJavaScript = {
    hasTypes: boolean;
};

export const callMe = () => {
    document.getElementById("greeting").textContent = "Color me your color, baby";
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById("greeting").textContent = "Hello world";
});
```

`src/pages/sample/sample1.astro`

```
---
import LayoutMain from "^layouts/LayoutMain.astro";
import "^scripts/sample"
---
<LayoutMain>
<p id="greeting"></p>
</LayoutMain>
```

Result: `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

`src/pages/sample/sample2.astro`

```
---
import LayoutMain from "^layouts/LayoutMain.astro";
import "^scripts/sample"
// same result as `import { callMe } from "^scripts/sample"`
---
<LayoutMain>
<p id="greeting"></p>
</LayoutMain>

<script is:inline>
// document.addEventListener moved from TS file
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById("greeting").textContent = "Hello world";
    callMe();
});
</script>
```

Result: "Hello world" with `ReferenceError: callMe is not defined`

> `src/scripts/sample.ts` moved to `public/sample.ts` for samples 3 and 4

`src/pages/sample/sample3.astro`

```
---
import LayoutMain from "^layouts/LayoutMain.astro";
---
<LayoutMain>
<p id="greeting"></p>
</LayoutMain>

<script is:inline>
    import "/sample.ts";
    callMe();
</script>
```

Result: `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

`src/pages/sample/sample4.astro`

```
---
import LayoutMain from "^layouts/LayoutMain.astro";
---
<LayoutMain>
<p id="greeting"></p>
</LayoutMain>

<script type="module">
    import { callMe } from "/sample.ts";
    callMe();
</script>
```

Result: `Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/sample.ts” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`

I have also seen `SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier` (referring to `type`)

**desired result**

Thank you for making it this far. Can you tell me how I can

- have an *external* TS file
- loaded by or within an Astro page
- that interacts with the DOM (via `document`)
- after `DOMContentLoaded` (or equivalent)

Relevant questions:

- [Do modules prevent the need to use the DOMContentLoaded listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63420821/do-modules-prevent-the-need-to-use-the-domcontentloaded-listener)
- [How to use document and window element in astro JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71495318/how-to-use-document-and-window-element-in-astro-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I must use  or  in order to have a script remain embedded in the HTML for "client scope". These scripts have access to window and document.

You can actually access the `document` and `window` object within the default processed `<srcipt>` tags (without any attribute).

To do that, reproduce `sample4.astro`, but *omit* the `type` attribute on the script tag and move your `sample.ts` file somewhere in the `src` directory (`^scripts` for you) so that you can [import it from javascript](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory) (note the last bullet point)

```
---
import LayoutMain from "^layouts/LayoutMain.astro";
---
<LayoutMain>
<p id="greeting"></p>
</LayoutMain>

<script>
    import { callMe } from "^scripts/sample";
    callMe();
</script>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fsrvg2?file=src%2Fgreet.ts,src%2Fpages%2Findex.astro&on=stackblitz) is a working reproduction.

Comment: OMG! Have been looking for this syntax for hours! Did not know it was as simple as just using import in the <script>. Thank you!